# Australian PR : Can I work in New Zealand

Tags: australia, new-zealand, working

I am moving to Australia under PR (Skilled - Independent (subclass 189) visa.
Does this make me eligible for working in New Zealand also.

Thank You

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you will be eligible to work in New Zealand too.
Source: http://glossary.immigration.govt.nz/australiancitizensandresidents.htm

Comment: But, if you're looking to take Australian citizenship note that time spent in New Zealand won't count towards the time you need to accrue to qualify for Australian citizenship.